# jQuery or php find multiple html strings within a single node and wrap with a span

Tags: php, jquery, string

After some digging, I'm still not getting any close with this.

I have a html string produced by this php...

This strips out all multiple white spaces.

For example the above outputs this string below, no other nodes contained, just text...

```
 1 Lorem ipsum 1.1 Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 1.2 Nulla non felis enim, a lacinia erat. 1.3 Donec ullamcorper feugiat lobortis. 1.4 Vivamus congue libero ut augue consectetur ultricies vitae eget quam. 2 Suspendisse 2.1 Ultrices volutpat tempus. 2.2 Aenean ullamcorper porta lacus, ut vehicula tortor dapibus hendrerit. 2.3 Proin condimentum est eget arcu mollis consequat. 2.4 Ut malesuada posuere lobortis. 2.5 Suspendisse gravida adipiscing nunc, et vehicula nunc tincidunt nec. 3 Tincidunt 3.1 Sed eget porta ligula. 3.2 Morbi vitae augue in eros tincidunt tincidunt consequat interdum dui. 3.3 Phasellus ante velit, venenatis et dignissim eu, semper vitae lectus. 3.4 Maecenas feugiat adipiscing tortor, non porttitor sem condimentum luctus. 3.5 Curabitur pharetra gravida ornare. 3.6 Donec tortor erat, posuere in ullamcorper eget, posuere sit amet purus. 3.7 Duis feugiat sollicitudin odio, ac molestie nulla elementum non. 4 Vestibulum 4.1 Tempor lectus sit amet purus condimentum nec condimentum dui viverra. 4.2 Duis sodales molestie fermentum. 4.3 Maecenas euismod, lacus ut ullamcorper condimentum, erat felis sodales lectus, a sodales ipsum lectus eu lorem. 4.3 Vivamus ac rhoncus est.
```

I am trying to find away of find all the numbers (1 , 1.2 , 1.3 , etc) and wrap them in a span.

I tried php but I was not having much luck...

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, "<span>".$yummy."</span>", $phrase);

echo $newphrase;
```

the above php is outputting this... `You should eat Array, Array, and Array every day.`

So I thought I could maybe try jquery, but I'm not sure if I'm approaching it correctly, please my code...

```
var points = [' 1 ',' 1.1 ',' 1.2 ',' 1.3 ',' 1.4 ',' 2 '];

$("p").html(this.html().replace( points,'<span>' + points + '</span>'));
```

I think I'm way off track but I can't really find much on pin pointing specific bits of string.

I made a fiddle of my jQuery... http://jsfiddle.net/XmU6p/

I guess in the mean time, I'm going to still pursue this problem. But if anyone could please share some pointers as to where I'm going wrong, I would be most grateful. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for all the php solutions! All had the same results, though I accepted the jQuery solution this time. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you need to actually loop through the array of values and do the replacement for each value. I'm not too familiar with PHP, so I've made an example using jQuery. Try this:

```
var points = [' 1 ',' 1.1 ',' 1.2 ',' 1.3 ',' 1.4 ',' 2 '];
$.each(points, function(i, val) {
    var $p = $('p');
    $p.html($p.html().replace(val, '<span>' + val + '</span>'));
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XmU6p/1/)

Comment: Thanks Rory this is great! It even works if I remove the spaces either side of the variable numbers? How does that work? Surely it will pick up all the numbers in the copy?

Comment: @JoshC That's correct, if there's any numbers within the text (not a delineating number) it will get those too. There's no real way around that unless you put those into a `li` tag for example.

Comment: Hmmm. Anyway, still has solved my problem. Many thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @Joshc even if this is a fine solution without any doubt, you should do such a string manipulation server-side, there is no reason do require JavaScript for this.

Comment: @axel.michel I agree. You should format this wall of text into `li` elements with the appropriate `list-style-type` set in CSS

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in PHP as well.  You have an array to string conversion (`"<span>$yummy</span>"`).  You need to loop over `$yummy` to add the spans:

```
array_walk($yummy, function ($elem) { return "<span>$elem</span>"; });
```

*Then* you can do:

```
$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

Comment: This is not what OP needs.

Comment: @ATOzTOA It's the preparation step missing from the OP's existing code: once you have your corrected `$yummy` array, you can use `str_replace` in the way the OP was attempting.

Comment: @ATOzTOA added the `str_replace` for people who are too dumb or lazy to figure this out for themselves

Comment: @ATOzTOA Perhaps your comment could also have included more explanation as to what you wanted to see improved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is also useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($healthy as $key => $food) {
 $newphrase = str_replace($food,'<span>'.$yummy[$key].'</span>',$phrase);
}


echo $newphrase;
```

Comment: @Joshc "Downvote" refers to somebody else marking this answer down. @ Ahmed That should be in a comment, not an edit to the question

Comment: There is no replace method in PHP.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there are a couple of reasons this isn't a great answer: 1) invalid PHP (`replace` is not a function, and `str_replace` doesn't take arguments in that order); nor, assuming you did mean `str_replace` is the result being assigned anywhere 2) No explanation of the general approach being used, just a code snippet, leaving the OP to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: sorry for the replace...typo

Comment: @AhmedHoban Wasn't me either, but it still won't work like this. You set the $newphrase in each loop, and replace one value of the  $phrase variable. So what you would get as a result if you echo $newphrase "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and ice-cream every day". And that was not the goal.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you don't need a loop or walk, you can use str_replace or preg_replace, both can handle arrays:

```
<?php
  $phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
  $yummy   = array("<span>pizza</span>", "<span>beer</span>", "<span>ice cream</span>");

  // regex variant...
  $healthy = array('/fruits/i', '/vegetables/i', '/fiber/i');      
  $newphrase = preg_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
  echo $newphrase;

  // string variant...
  $healthy = array('fruits', 'vegetables', 'fiber');
  $newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
  echo $newphrase;
?>
```

I would prefer the regular expression variant (preg_replace), to have a bit more flexibility in matching.

Comment: `str_replace` can handle arrays as well. The problem lies in producing the appropriate replacement array.

Comment: @IMSoP yes for sure you are right, I've updated the example. I used preg_replace simply because it has a bit more power.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to experiment with this too

Comment: It should be noted that it's important to understand the difference between the two, though, particularly as the original (non-food-related) examples contained `.`s, which have special meaning in regexes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your PHP example is failing is that `$yummy` is an array, but `"<span>"` is a string. So the line `"<span>".$yummy."</span>"` converts the array into the string `"Array"`, then adds the other strings to either side of it, and returns that as a single string.

Since what you want is an array to give to `str_replace`, you need to construct (e.g. using a `foreach` loop or [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map)) a new array which contains the `"<span>"` and `"</span>"` around each element - ultimately resulting in something like `$yummyWithSpan = array("<span>pizza</span>", "<span>beer</span>", "<span>ice cream</span>");`

An alternative approach would be to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback), with a callback function that adds the `"<span>"` and `"</span>"`, but you will then need a working knowledge of how regular expressions work, which may or may not be something you want to get into.

Comment: Thank your for explaining. I'm digging into php when and where I need it so this is useful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

foreach ($healthy as $key => $value) {
  $phrase = str_replace($value, "<span>".$yummy[$key]."</span>",$phrase);
}

echo $phrase;
```

Output:

```
You should eat <span>pizza</span>, <span>beer</span>, and <span>ice cream</span> every day.
```